# Error Page redirect in Sitefinity 8

Tags: content-management-system

I have an issue with Sitefinity about 404 page, after I try to change the webconfig as the example from Sitefinity forum, but it doesn't work. Any idea for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think You can't set it in web config, I have tried and find another solution. so check on this code below and put it on your globar.asax

```
        int statusCode = Context.Response.StatusCode;

        if ((Context.Response.StatusCode == 404 || Context.Response.StatusCode == 400) && Request.Path != (ApplicationConfig.Instance.PrefixLang + "/404"))
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Redirect(new Uri(Request.Url.ToString()).GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + ApplicationConfig.Instance.PrefixLang + "/404");
        }
        else if (statusCode >= 500 && statusCode < 600 && Request.Path != (ApplicationConfig.Instance.PrefixLang + "/404") &&
            Request.Path.ToLower().IndexOf("sitefinity") == -1)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Redirect(new Uri(Request.Url.ToString()).GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + ApplicationConfig.Instance.PrefixLang + "/404");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The below web.config configuration works fine for me:

```
<authentication mode="None" />
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" >
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/error-pages/404" />
</customErrors>
```

...

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
    <clear />
    <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <error statusCode="404" path="/error-pages/404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```